# "git clean -xdf" with some additional filter

Tags: git

Is it possible to do **git clean -xdf** with some additional filter? What I want to do is delete all untracked files but keep files with a certain file extension.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use the `-e` option to specify an exclude pattern.

Example: This deletes all untracked files except those with the `.txt` extension:

```
git clean -xdfe *.txt
```